# Link a specific stackoverflow private team to MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

My company has 2 separate private SO teams. One is developer focused and the other data science focused. Both use email domain as a means for membership to the team. The developer team was set up first and integrated into MS Teams. We are now trying to integrate the data science one into a different team in MS Teams but there is no option in the stackoverflow MS Teams app which will allow me to select which SO team I want to link to and it defaults to the developer team every time.

How can I get the SO app in MS Teams to link the SO team I want it to link to?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on it?
Are you developing Microsoft Teams apps?

Comment: Hi - No, just trying to use the normal integration between stackoverflow for private teams and MS Teams. But for some reason, since a different SO team is already integrated with MS teams in our company, I cant seem to link the second one

Comment: Could you please clarify how you are integrating SO team with MS Teams?

Comment: I've been integrating though this link which takes you to AppSource to download the integration https://stackoverflow.co/teams/integrations/microsoft-teams/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments everyone. I didn't manage to solve the problem but I did get to an answer. After leaving membership of one team to see if that changed anything for integrating the second team, I now get this error message:

[image]

It seems like its not possible to link 2 different private teams to the same MS teams tenant at the moment.

If anyone does know of way around this, I would still appreciate the feedback but I will mark this as answered for now.

Comment: Done, sorry about that